# Android Timed Async Task

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

Hi currently i have the following code which utilizes Asycn Task and Timer.

My async task is basically trying to send a HTTP GET method from a URL where the response from the server could varies depending on connection and load.

**What i would like to do** is to have a timed async task. Where, it will schedule an AsyncTask every X second BUT if there is currently an Async Task in progress i would have to kill it first. Then start a new one.

Here is the code that i have at the moment:

```
private static boolean running = false;
Timer myTimer;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /* REST OF CODE OMITTED */
        MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(myTask, 0, 10000);
}

/* REST OF CODE OMITTED */

private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        if(!running){
            Log.i("TAG", "NEW TIMER STARTED.");
            RetrieveChatMessage task = new RetrieveChatMessage();
            task.execute();
            running = true;
        }else{
            running = false;
        }
    }
}

private class RetrieveChatMessage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Chat>> {
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Chat> doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Chat> cList = null;
        String jResult = null;

        Log.i("TAG", "RETRIEVING CHAT MESSAGE");

        try {
            jResult = ((new HttpRetriever())).getChatList(mAccount.email, mAccount.passwd);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if(jResult != null){
                Log.i("TAG", "JSON DATA: " + jResult);
                cList = (new ChatHandlers()).getChatList(jResult);
            }else{
                cList = null;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG", "JSON Exception " + e.toString());
        }

        return cList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Chat> result) {
        Log.i("TAG", "ON POST EXECUTE");
        if(result != null){
              // Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

To be honest the code above works with slight issues:
1. It seems to execute the Async randomly, instead of every 10 seconds.
2. When i go to another activity, somewhat it prevents other Async task from doing its job (Which is also trying to retrieve JSON response from server).

I am not too worried about the later problem (and that is not the question i am asking). I just would like to know how to have a proper timed Async Task. Can anyone point me to a direction.

Thank you.

EDIT #1:

after reading @thepoosh comment's i tried the following (i put it in onCreate):

```
scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Parsing RSS feed:
        // myFeedParser.doSomething();
        Log.w("THUMBQOO", "NEW TASK STARTED");
        retrieveChat();
    }
  }, 0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Result: i have a consistent execution of Task. However, it seems that retrieveChat(); is never be called after the first execution.

Comment: you should use `ScheduledPoolExecutor` instead of Timer

Comment: could you elaborate more? perhaps with an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a very good way of accomplishing this (my answer here below) :

Use a Handler, create a HandlerThread and keep posting messages to this handler.
For the handlers "handleMessage" method, you can do your task and again send a message back to the MessageQueue.

```
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread(<name>);
thread.start();

Looper looper = thread.getLooper();
CustomHandler handler = new CustomHandler(looper);

// The CustomHandler class
class CustomHandler extends Handler {

      public CustomHandler(Looper looper) {
          super(looper);
      }

      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          //Do your operation here

          handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(msg, <delayTime>);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `AsyncTask` is not used for long operations .Check [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

You should use a `Thread` that uses a interface to notify `UI` or you can simply use a `Handler` which is the most Preffered way in android. Simply you can do a task repeatedly for every 10 seconds by

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
  // do work
  handler.postDelayed(10000);
}
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Handler object to maintain future task executor...

```
private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();
```

Write a thread which will execute your future task...

```
private Runnable mTimerExecutor = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //write your code what you want to do after the specified time elapsed

        if(!running){
            RetrieveChatMessage task = new RetrieveChatMessage();
            task.execute();
            running = true;
        }else{
            running = false;
        }

    }
};
```

Call your future tast executor with time using hanlder...

```
mTimerHandler.postDelayed(mTimerExecutor, 10000);
```

You can cancle your future task executor any time by this...

```
mTimerHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimerExecutor);
```